# Does Scala have something similar to C#'s explicit interface implementation?

Tags: c#, scala, inheritance, traits

In C#, you can implement interfaces explicitely. The explicitely implemented methods can then only be called through a variable that has the interface as its static type. This allows you to avoid name/return type conflicts and provide different implementations of the same method depending on the static type of `this`.

For example:

```
interface IFoo
{
    int DoSomething();
}

interface IBar
{
    string DoSomething();
}

class Impl : IFoo, IBar
{
    int IFoo.DoSomething() { /* Implementation for IFoo */ }
    string IBar.DoSomething() { /* A different implementation for IBar */ }
    public void DoSomething() { /* Yet another implementation for Impl */ }
}
```

How would you handle this case in Scala:

```
trait Foo {
    def doSomething(): Int
}

trait Bar {
    def doSomething(): String
}

class Impl extends Foo with Bar {
    /* only one "doSomething()" visible here (that of Bar?) */
    /* what now... ? */
}
```

Comment: You can use generics T? Not 100% what you are getting at but it seems you can use it. You trying to return a different type based on the same signature method? For example: you can have T DoSomething<T>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to make your class follow two separate incompatible interfaces, you'd have to write wrappers instead.  For instance,

```
implicit case class ImplAsFoo(impl: Impl) extends Foo {
  def asFoo = this
  def doSomething: Int = 5
}
```

Now you can

```
impl.asFoo
```

at the use-site to switch over to the Foo wrapping.

In some cases, though, it may be more natural use the type class pattern instead to provide pluggable functionality:

```
trait IFoo[A] { def doSomething: Int }
trait IBar[A] { def doSomething: String }

// These need to be companions so :paste if you're using REPL
class Impl { def doSomething { println("Hey!") } }
object Impl {
  implicit object FooImpl extends IFoo[Impl] { def doSomething = 5 }
  implicit object BarImpl extends IBar[Impl] { def doSomething = "salmon" }
}

def needsFoo[A <: Impl: IFoo](a: A) = implicitly[IFoo[Impl]].doSomething

scala> needsFoo(new Impl)
res1: Int = 5

scala> (new Impl).doSomething
Hey!
```

It's not *exactly* the same, but this also handles the issue of having different implementations without naming schemes tripping you up.  (If you needed to `doSomething` with the `impl` object, you'd pass it as a parameter in the `implicit object` that handles that case.)

If you've already got traits, then of course this won't help you.  But when you're designing from scratch, rather than having a pile of traits with incompatible methods you might instead try type classes.

Finally, if you cannot help having a bunch of untyped things jumbled together out of which you need to pick the `Foo`s, you have to invent more elaborate schemes like so:

```
trait CanBeFoo { def asFoo: Foo }
trait Foo { def doSomething: Int }

// :paste these two together
class Impl extends CanBeFoo {
  def doSomething { println("Ho!") } 
  def asFoo = ImplAsFoo(this)
}
case class ImplAsFoo(impl: Impl) extends Foo {
  def doSomething = 6
}

val myList = List("salmon", new Impl, new Foo { def doSomething = 4 })
def doIt(f: Foo) { println(f.doSomething) }
myList.foreach {
  case f: Foo => doIt(f)
  case cf: CanBeFoo => doIt(cf.asFoo)
  case _ => println("nuh-uh")
}

// Produces
// nuh-uh
// 6
// 4
```

You might prefer an intermediate map:

```
myList.map{ case cf: CanBeFoo => cf.asFoo; case x => x }.foreach{
  case f: Foo => println(f.doSomething)
  case _ => println("nuh-uh")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, those are strictly incompatible base types. When a class extends a trait, it has that trait as a part of its type identity. It cannot have mutually incompatible type identities as would be the case for any class that `extends Foo with Bar` (as you wrote those traits).